# linux doesn't detect dead tcp connections

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, centos

After restarting my server side application, my client side OS doesn't detect dead tcp connections. The zombie connections will stay in established state, and never be closed by OS. Is anyone hava any idea about this?

This is the server side connections on port 9888:
[image]

This is the client side connections to the server:
[image]

Some information of my OS:
[image]

Comment: TCP connection by default doesn't have any kind of keep-alive. If the other end has gone down abruptly without sending `FIN` you will never know that the connection is dead unless you try to send something.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So I need to `send` something, `recv` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, you need to send something, I suggest some kind of keep-alive signaling method in your protocol. Of you can enable the built-in keep-alive signaling by setting `SO_KEEPALIVE` (but watch out, because the default timeout is two hours I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use TCP keep alive mechanism to detect the dead peers. As rightly mentioned in the comments you need to call set following socket options using setsockopt function,

SO_KEEPALIVE - To enable/disable the TCP keep alive mechanism

TCP_KEEPIDLE - IDLE time (in seconds) after which TCP starts sending keepalive probes

TCP_KEEPCNT - Maximum number of keepalive probes TCP should send before dropping the connection

TCP_KEEPINTVL - The time (in seconds) between individual keepalive probes

So for example if you set ideal time = 60 seconds, cnt = 5 and interval = 2 seconds, the system will drop the connection after 70 seconds of inactivity.

More details are available at following website

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: To the OP: Note that only `SO_KEEPALIVE` is portable, the other options are Linux specific.